# Syncing actions between Windows Phone apps. Where do I begin?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've an idea of what I want to do, but limited knowledge on how to search for the tools or APIs I would need to accomplish it.

I'd like to have the ability for a user to share an item from my app to another user using the same app. When the item's shared (or subscribed to), I want the actions to be kept in sync between them.

My thought on this sharing would be like a code subscription to the actions through some intermediary.

If User A deletes/changes something, I'd send a message with an ID and an Action that gets automatically handled in User B's app (or any other subscribers).

When one user's not in the item, changes stack up, and when the load the item the changes are applied FIFO to sync the item.

I'd thought about using SkyDrive to keep the items on some level in sync, but I've only been able to upload/download. I want to learn to implement "real-time" changes.

I've searched a bit and here on SO there're some sightly similar questions that only point back to implementing SkyDrive in an app.

Again, I'm not too clear on what category of service I'm trying to describe, so if someone can help me to clarify I can at least search better. (For example, do I need to get Azure and do something with accounts?).

Comment: Azure Mobile services might be a place to look. You can post to an API that a change happened to generate a notification to the receiver's app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This applies to Windows Phone 8; some or all of this may not apply to Phone 7:

Windows Phone offers a "Push notification" service/mechanism which might be an option (or partial solution). A phone app can create/subscribe to a push channel. An external agent (app, server, etc.) can then post an http request containing notification data to a special URL which causes the push to be delivered to the subscribing phone. However, push notifications do have some idiosyncrasies and limitations. They work best for updating live tiles and delivering "toast" notifications when your app isn't running. You can use "raw" push to deliver any content you like, but it has its quirks as to when and how notifications are delivered (app running/not running, etc.).

You can use background agents to do things on the phone while your app is not running. However, background agents have limitations - they are typically invoked on a more or less fixed infrequent schedule (~30 min), and have strict limits on resource usage. A background agent cannot be triggered by a push, unless registered as a VOIP app.

You can use sockets on the phone as you would on just about any other platform, to communicate using something like mqtt.

For any two phones to sync up with each other, you'd need some sort of server to act as a central repository for shared data and for the phones to accomplish a registration/subscription. It wouldn't necessarily need Azure; a website might be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed look at the options. Can you give a little more detail when you say a website may be sufficient?

Comment: Web hosting services typically allow you to deploy database and code to their servers so you can set up interactive web sites and/or web services. Essentially, your phone app makes web (http) requests to send or receive data to/from your web service (a web service acts like an interactive website except that instead of sending HTML for human-readable display, it exchanges JSON, XML, or whatever other format you decide upon).

Comment: I see. Not too familiar but will explore the various options you've mentioned. I believe this has gotten me on a good start. Thanks.